# Newbie question on Ada generic package with a protected object

Tags: generics, ada

I am still learning to use the language, so these are all newbie questions, that I hope may also be useful for other:

In an example by Dale Stanbrough from rmit.edu.au:  [Link](http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/dale/ada/style/sec_6a.html)

```
generic
    type Item is private;
    Maximum_Buffer_Size : in Positive;
package Bounded_Buffer_Package is
   subtype Buffer_Index is Positive range 1..Maximum_Buffer_Size;
   subtype Buffer_Count is Natural  range 0..Maximum_Buffer_Size;
   type    Buffer_Array is array (Buffer_Index) of Item;

   protected type Bounded_Buffer is
      entry Get (X : out Item);
      entry Put (X : in Item);
   private
      Get_Index : Buffer_Index := 1;
      Put_Index : Buffer_Index := 1;
      Count     : Buffer_Count := 0;
      Data      : Buffer_Array;
   end Bounded_Buffer;
end Bounded_Buffer_Package;

-------------------------------------------------------------

package body Bounded_Buffer_Package is
   protected body Bounded_Buffer is
       entry Get (X : out Item) when Count > 0 is
       begin
           X := Data(Get_Index);
           Get_Index := (Get_Index mod Maximum_Buffer_Size) + 1;
           Count := Count - 1;
      end Get;

      entry Put (X : in Item) when Count < Maximum_Buffer_Size is
      begin
          Data(Put_Index) := X;
          Put_Index  := (Put_Index mod Maximum_Buffer_Size) + 1;
          Count := Count + 1;
      end Put;

    end Bounded_Buffer;
end Bounded_Buffer_Package;
```

I have used the package as follows:

```
with Text_IO; use Text_IO;
with Bounded_Buffer_Package;  

procedure test_buffer is
    package my_buffer_instance is new Bounded_Buffer_Package(Item => Integer, Maximum_Buffer_Size =>100);
    my_buffer : my_buffer_instance.Bounded_Buffer;
    val : Integer;
begin
    my_buffer.Put(17);
    my_buffer.Get(val);
    Put_line(Integer'Image(val));
end test_buffer;
```

==== EDITED ===

The code works, but I have the following question:

Is this the correct way to use generic package with a protected object?
If not, what is the right way to instantiate the bounded buffer object?

=== EDIT 2 - clarification ===

What I want to ask is: Am I unintentionally allocating all the data (including the buffer that can be big) *twice*?  Once in the instantiation of package `my_buffer_instance`, and second time in `my_buffer` definition?

Is my understanding that `new Bounded_Buffer_Package` only defines the type, `Bounded_Buffer` but does not allocate memory until the type is used correct?

Comment: @KenWhite - thank you for your commnet, the question was rephrased, with only the main question present.

Answer (score 2):

I can’t help feeling that `Bounded_Buffer_Package` (by the way, why add the `_Package`? just adds another 8 characters for the eye to skip over) could do with a bit more information hiding! The user doesn’t need to know about the types and subtypes used internally by the PO.

That’s not the point of your question(s). The buffer is indeed reserved when the protected object is declared; the generic instantiation may reserve a few bytes (e.g. to do with elaboration checks) but not the buffer.

A generic that declares an *object* rather than a type will definitely reserve space for that object on instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

Protected objects are intended to be used as shared data between tasks. Your example has the main task calling both put and get. The intended use of a protected object should have at least one task working as the producer, calling the Put entry, and one or more tasks working as the consumer, calling the Get entry. The protected object will handle all the locking and task queuing issues for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do understand the purpose of the protected data (the main task it just to see that I can access the methods), 
My question is about what happens during package instantiation - I have added a clarification to the original questions, I hope my question is clearer now.